# GitHub Readme Stack Exchange

Tags: app, users

### Screenshots

#### Standard Layout

[image: Diego Borba StackOverflow]
[image: Diego Borba Arqade]

#### Compact Layout

[image: Diego Borba StackOverflow]
[image: Diego Borba Arqade]

### About

Dynamically generate your status for **any *Stack Exchange* site**!

I've created it based on [*github-readme-stackoverflow*](https://github.com/omidnikrah/github-readme-stackoverflow), but I improved it to be used with any *Stack Exchange* site instead of only *StackOverflow*.

I've also added **icons for each site** in the cards.

#### Download

You can use it now in *https://github-readme-stack-exchange.vercel.app*, but **it's highly recommended** to [deploy on your own](https://github.com/diegoborbadev/github-readme-stack-exchange#deploy-your-own).

### Contact

You can reach me on [*Linkedin*](https://www.linkedin.com/in/diegoborbadev/) or [*Twitter/X*](https://twitter.com/diegoborbadev)

### Code

**Language**: *Javascript*
**Framework**: *NodeJs*
**Repository**: [*github-readme-stack-exchange*](https://github.com/diegoborbadev/github-readme-stack-exchange)

Feel free to suggest improvements or new features!